# New app in Facebook, needs approval?

Tags: facebook

I´m programming an app in Facebook. My code is ready but I don´t know if my app needs to be approved or something like that.

Answer (score 6):

A Facebook application does normally not need to go through any approval process to go public, all you need to do is to switch Sandbox mode to disabled.

To find the Sandbox Mode setting:

1. Go yo your [application dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).
2. Select the application you wish to publish.
3. Click edit app.
4. Go to Settings -> Advanced.
5. It should be here under the Authentication category.

The only times you need to go through a approval process are:

- When you add an [open graph activity](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/) which isn't standard.
- When you apply for the advanced [Marketing API](https://www.facebook.com/marketingapi).

Answer (score 1):

About a year ago, there was an option to "send your application to the catalog" (or similiar), now I can't see it.

Just remember to disable sandbox mode and that should be all.